# Contact form doesn't work on phone (works everywhere else)

Tags: php, android, html, ios, contact-form

I've made this php which will send me messages right to my inbox. Even though the script works fine on desktops and laptops I can't use on phones. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? ( I tried the form on iPhone 6+ and Samsung Alpha)

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header('Location: message-sent.html#contact'); exit();
?>
```

And this is the html code for the phone.

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="6u">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u">
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u">
            <input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Send Message"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: so what is your error message? what is your `$_POST` shows?

Comment: In fact I can't see an error (on my phone).. It does redirect to the thank you page so you think that everything is ok. But There is no sent message. I tried sending messages from 2 devices to different recipient each time (3 dif email accounts with different client) but with no results. I searched in spams I searched everywhere. There was no message at all. :(

Comment: check your mail server logs

Comment: My server logs? How do I do that? You mean the server that my domain is hosted? (that means that I have to ask godaddy to send me mail logs?)

Comment: when you use `mail(` command in php. that means that you have an access to some mail server, that accept any sender (trust your php). that is very rare when public server accept any sender. so what mail server do you use? if your `mail(` command passed successfully, I see no problem with your client side device. I see only problem: why if you sent mail, you didn't get it on other(recipient) side.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The thing is that I am the recipient. This contact form is suppose to be on my website so people can send mails to my mail clients (eg. gmail or mydomain.com ) . All I did was to test it from all devices. It didn't work on phones. So I am not sure how to answer your question. I hope this comment helps though.

Comment: and again. try to understand my point of view. Usually when people say *this page doesn't work* that mean that there is an error message on the page, or some behavior is different than expected.  But in your case you told, that page has no errors, and it successfully goes to your `header('Location: message-sent.html#contact');` that means that PHP got success response from mail server when `mail`

Comment: Yes but the only mail server I have is the one that I am receiving messages (gmail) which is different from the server of my domain (I also have a mail client there too). I tried them both (by changing the recipient each time in php). I searched in my ftp folder and the only logs I found are about my domain and the ftp itself. There is no such thing as mail logs or something similar. :/  So what do I do? Even if there was something I don't even know what to look for I am not that experienced with these things. :/

Comment: @user3482394 Has it ever shown "Error!" on the desktop or laptop? Try making the script fail on the laptop/desktop and confirm that it shows the error message.

Comment: Yes once...  I had a wrong syntax and it returned error. So from my side is everything good? Should I contact my server support?

Comment: I guess so. I don't _see_ anything wrong with your script.